# Property 'data1' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

```
const Home: NextPage = ({data1}:{data1:any}) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(data1);

  const handleAddClick = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

.....

}


export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // Fetch data from external API
  const fs = require("fs");
  const json = require("./db.json");

  
  const data1 = await res.json()

  return { props: { data1 } }
}
```

erros show me as below,

Property 'data1' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ data1: any; }'.ts(2322)

how to fix it , I have no idea for this.

i just want to pass the the value data1 to the page Home .

Comment: Can you show us where you're calling `getServerSideProps`? I'm guessing you're passing the results from this function directly into `NextPage` as the props?

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props
it is a Nextjs interface ,  it runs by each request using the data returned by getServerSideProps .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default type of `NextPage` is `{}`, so you should add your type to the generic type of `NextPage<Props>` to make it recognize your type.

```
type Props = {
  data1: any
}

const Home: NextPage<Props> = ({data1}: Props) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(data1);

  const handleAddClick = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
}
```